# Add navigational dots in beamer presentation with Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am creating a beamer presentation using theme Madrid. However I like the navigational dots that show up at the top in the Frankfurt theme. Is there a way to include them in my presentation? I've looked around and it seems a lot more people have asked how to get rid of the dots than to add them in.

Comment: Can you please give a MWE to play with?

Comment: `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}` Does this do what you want?

Comment: @Benjamin I just tried with `smoothbars`. It produces the navigation bar. But there appears a thin horizontal white space at the right side of the top margin of the bar.

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \section{sec1}
   \subsection{s1}
   \begin{frame}{frame1.1}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{frame1.2}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}

   \section{sec2}
   \subsection{s2}
   \begin{frame}{frame2.1}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{frame2.2}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}

   \section{sec3}
   \subsection{s3}
   \begin{frame}{frame3.1}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}
   \begin{frame}{frame3.2}
    blah, blah, blah
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]