# How to remove a specific frame from the top navigation bar but keep its frame numbering visible in beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I am making a presentation with `beamer` using the `Madrid` theme. I am removing the specific frame titled `Special Frame` from the top navigation bar using the command `\buttenoff`. But it's hiding the frame number also.

### teststyle.sty

```
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{circles} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47373/114006
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437578/114006
\makeatletter
% Remember the way beamer did it before
\let\beamer@old@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
% Tell it to do nothing with the slides entry
\newcommand\bulletoff{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\relax}
% Reset it to the old ways
\newcommand\bulleton{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@old@writeslidentry}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}           % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326553/114006
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148696/114006
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55590/114006

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401409/114006
\usepackage{environ}

% Custom font for a frame.
\newcommand{\customframefont}[1]{
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{#1}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{#1}
}
\NewEnviron{framefont}[1]{
\customframefont{#1} % for itemize/enumerate
{#1 % For the text outside itemize/enumerate
\BODY
}
\customframefont{\normalsize}
}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

### test.tex

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}  

\usepackage{teststyle}
% \graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\title{Presentation Title}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}

\author{Presenter Name} 
\date{August, 2021} 

\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412733/114006
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\frametitle{Outline} 
\tableofcontents %[pausesections,pausesubsections,subsectionstyle=shaded]
\end{frame}
}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{Section 1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section One}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 2}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------

\bulletoff\section*{}
\begin{frame}{Special Frame}     % The frame number is not visible!
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg}
% \bulletoff\section*{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\Huge{\centerline{Thank You.}} 
\huge{\centerline{Any Question?}}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

I like to make the hidden frame number visible on the specific frame titled `Special Frame`. Only the title frame, TOC frame, last frame should not be affected i.e., they shouldn't have frame numbers. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the definition of the command `\beamer@writeslidentry` you redefine, you see

> ```
> \def\beamer@writeslidentry{%
>   \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
>   {%else
>     \addtocontents{nav}%
>       {\protect\headcommand{%
>           \protect\slideentry{\the\c@section}{\the\c@subsection}{\the\c@subsectionslide}%
>           {\beamer@framestartpage/\beamer@frameendpage}{\lastsubsection}{\the\c@part}}}%
>     \addtocontents{nav}%
>       {\protect\headcommand{%
>         \protect\beamer@framepages{\beamer@framestartpage}{\beamer@frameendpage}}}%
>     \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
>   }%
> }
> ```

So it only executes under some condition, then it writes some auxiliary information (probably to influence the top navigation) and finally ends with `\clearpage` and `\beamer@notesactions`. Since you only want to avoid influencing the top navigation, it seems like a good idea to remove only the `\addtocontents` calls.

This seems to have the intended effect:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}  

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{circles} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47373/114006
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437578/114006
\makeatletter
% Remember the way beamer did it before
\let\beamer@old@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@new@writeslidentry{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}%
}

% Tell it to do nothing with the slides entry
\newcommand\bulletoff{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@new@writeslidentry}
% Reset it to the old ways
\newcommand\bulleton{\let\beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@old@writeslidentry}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}           % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326553/114006
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148696/114006
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55590/114006

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401409/114006
\usepackage{environ}

% Custom font for a frame.
\newcommand{\customframefont}[1]{
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{#1}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{#1}
}
\NewEnviron{framefont}[1]{
\customframefont{#1} % for itemize/enumerate
{#1 % For the text outside itemize/enumerate
\BODY
}
\customframefont{\normalsize}
}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\title{Presentation Title}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}

\author{Presenter Name} 
\date{August, 2021} 

\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412733/114006
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\frametitle{Outline} 
\tableofcontents %[pausesections,pausesubsections,subsectionstyle=shaded]
\end{frame}
}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{Section 1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section One}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Section 2}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------

\bulletoff\section*{}
\begin{frame}{Special Frame}     % The frame number is not visible!
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida.
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg}
% \bulletoff\section*{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\Huge{\centerline{Thank You.}} 
\huge{\centerline{Any Question?}}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution!